# Override edit template in sonata admin

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-3.4

I need to add `HTML` editor in edit form of `Sonata admin` so I am trying to override edit template in `Sonata admin`. My `Symfony version is 3.4`

Following this [link](https://medium.com/@mounabenhmida/symfony-4-wysiwyg-editors-72714cad8916) for the HTML editor. Stuck in `step 3` and `6` as per my understanding I put an `edit.html.twig` file in `app/resource/views` directory and added the code given in `step 3`. Then I added template route in the `sonata_admin.yml` file but getting this error.

> Unrecognized option "0" under "sonata_admin.templates"

Sonata_admin.yml file

```
sonata_admin:
assets:
    extra_javascripts:
        - bundles/sonatapage/sonata-page.back.min.js
    extra_stylesheets:
        - bundles/sonatapage/sonata-page.back.min.css

templates:
    edit: edit.html.twig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add a template directory on the root of your project then add `sonata/CRUD`directory just for understanding and add `edit.html.twig` in that directory. 
add the path of the edit.html.twig file after template directory like `Sonata/CRUD/edit.html.twig` and add it on sonata_admin.yml

your sonata_admin.yml file will be like

```
sonata_admin:
   assets:
      extra_javascripts:
        - bundles/sonatapage/sonata-page.back.min.js
      extra_stylesheets:
        - bundles/sonatapage/sonata-page.back.min.css

   templates:
      edit: Sonata/CRUD/edit.html.twig
```